# Are ε(epsilon) and δ(delta) related in the formal definition of "limit"?

Tags: limits

***FIRST QUESTIONS***
Having this image as a reference:

[Option A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu1vG.jpg)

-The interval in "y-axis" where "b" is (b-ε,b+ε). 
-The interval in "x-axis" where "a" is (a-δ,a+δ).

My question is:
Are those extremes of both intervals related?
To give an analogy, if I had this function -> f(a+δ) would it always return me b+ε?

---

At the beginning I thougth it would, nevertheless, I watched this other image/video:

[Option B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XtBk.png)

This image is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYVVPqphPS0) Time: 1:08:45

I interpret his words as that those intervals are not related as I thought at the begining.
In his example the interval of δ(delta) is smaller than the interval of ε(epsilon).

Given "k"= "Interval of "x points" "associated to" ε(epsilon) interval extremes"...

Could "interval of δ(delta)"> k?
Or...  "interval of δ(delta)"≤ k, always?

---

***SECOND QUESTIONS***
I am not sure If I understand well when a limit is defined, so I will describe informally what I think I know, so that you could help me in case I am wrong.

I will use "Option A" image as a reference.

So, as far as I know:
"$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$" is defined if, for any epsilon interval (which, in this case, contains b), there is a delta interval (which contains a), in which fuction is defined (defined in the entire opened interval, except possibly at a).

Comment: Suppose $f$ is a constant function $f(x) = c$, in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the $δ$ - set can be the the whole $\mathbb{R}$, while the $ε$ - set is just $(c - ε, c + ε)$. So there is no standard relation between the two sets. The $δ$ - set always depends on $ε$, but not with a standard way.

Comment: I guess its worth saying that the reason $\delta$ depends on $epsilon$ is because it has to be able to take values arbitrarily close to zero but not zero, there's no constant that can do that.

Comment: Your idea presented in question is more formally handled using *neighborhoods*. A neighborhood of $a$ is any open interval containing $a$. The limit definition then can be worded as: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =b$ if for every neighborhood $I$ of $b$ there is a corresponding neighborhood $J$ of $a$ such that $f(J\setminus\{a\}) \subseteq I$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the value of $\delta$ needs to depend on both the function $f$ and the positive number $\varepsilon$. So they are related in that sense, but there's no simple rule that always applies.

Notice that in the limit definition, we need to know that given ($f$ and) $\varepsilon$, and after defining $\delta$, we have

$$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x)-b| < \varepsilon \tag{1}$$

That's a forward implication $\implies$, not an "if and only if" $\iff$. So it's fine to have $\delta$ smaller than necessary, since if $0 < \delta_2 < \delta_1$ and the larger $\delta_1$ does work, then also

$$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta_2 \implies 0 < |x-a| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x)-b| < \varepsilon $$

Though there is always a maximum value of $\delta$ which makes statement (1) true. If the function is increasing, this will mean that at least one of $f(a-\delta)=b-\varepsilon$ or $f(a+\delta)=b+\varepsilon$ is true. In your "Option A", $f$ is increasing near $(a,b)$, but it's a bit of a special case that $f(a-\delta)=b-\varepsilon$ AND $f(a+\delta)=\varepsilon$. This is only possible if the three points $(a-\delta,b-\varepsilon), (a,b), (a+\delta,b+\varepsilon)$ happen to be on a straight line with non-negative slope. So that image is misleading by implying that's the usual case.

On the other hand, suppose $f(x)=x^3$, and $(a,b)=(1,1)$. If $\varepsilon=7$, then the largest valid $\delta$ is $1$. Then $f(a-\delta)=f(0)=0>1-\varepsilon$ and $f(a+\delta)=f(2)=8=1+\varepsilon$. So $\delta=1$ is smaller than necessary on the $x<a$ side, but we must have $\delta \leq 1$ because of the $x>a$ side.

Also, it's not good enough to look at just the endpoints $f(a+\delta)$ and $f(a-\delta)$. If $f(x) = \sin x$, and $(a,b)=0$ then no matter how small $\varepsilon < 1$ is, setting $\delta=\pi$ gives $|f(a-\delta)| = |f(a+\delta)| = 0 < \varepsilon$, but that doesn't mean $f(x)<\varepsilon$ for all the non-zero $x$ in $|x-a|<\delta \iff -\pi < x < \pi$.

> "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$" is defined if, for any epsilon interval (which, in this case, contains b), there is a delta interval (which contains a), in which function is defined (defined in the entire opened interval, except possibly at a).

No, the function $f$ needs to be not just defined. The point of a limit is that the values of $f$ need to get closer and closer to a specific limit value when $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$. (If that limit value is the same as $f(a)$, we say $f$ is continuous at $a$. If the limit exists but is not equal to $f(a)$, we say $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $a$.)

It's also helpful that we can have $\delta$ smaller than it really needs to be, because for many functions it's difficult or impossible to find a formula for the exact biggest value $\delta$ could possibly be.

Consider

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \cos \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases} $$

near $a=0$, and suppose $\varepsilon = \frac 12$. $f$ is certainly defined everywhere. But no matter how small $\delta>0$ is, there's a natural number $n$ so that $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi} < \frac{1}{2 n \pi} < \delta$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}\right) = -1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{2n \pi}\right) = 1$, so no matter what $b$ is, it can't be the case that $0 < |x| < \delta$ always implies $|f(x)-b| < \varepsilon$.

There's also the game idea which often helps understand limits. Lemmy and Nora are playing a game. Both of them know a function $f$ and a real number $a$, where $f$ is defined at least in some interval containing $a$. Lemmy claims the limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists, and Nora claims that limit does not exist. In this game,

1. Lemmy names a value $b$ (the claimed value of the limit).
2. Nora names a positive number $\varepsilon$.
3. Lemmy names a positive number $\delta$.
4. Nora names a number $x$, which must satisfy $0 < |x-a| < \delta$.

If $|f(x)-b| < \varepsilon$, Lemmy wins. Otherwise, Nora wins.

If there's a strategy Lemmy can use to always win, then the limit exists and is equal to $b$. If there's a strategy Nora can use to always win, then the limit does not exist. (Since there's no randomness in this game and no possibility of a draw, one of them must have a winning strategy.)